# Auto generate Guid with EntityTypeConfiguration

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first, identity

I can specify Guid auto generation using Attribute

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
```

on a Class' Property. But is there a way to achieve the same Goal using EntityTypeConfiguration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was looking for this Option in a HasKey Method Result.
However it was in the Property:

```
entity.Property(e => e.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
```